# How to check who view your directory on UNIX/LINUX?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Is it possible to see who (in the group) has accessed a certain directory on a Linux or Unix machine?

What is the command?

Comment: What do you mean? To know who use opened files in some directory you may use commands `lsof` or `fuser`. If you want to know, who had open/edit files in past, I need to disappoint you: it's impossible!

Comment: I mean, I have a directory under `~/my_user/` that is 'read/write-able' to people in my group. I'm am required to let them read it, and possibly write to it. But I am a bit paranoid that people will change things in it without letting me know. So I'm interested in seeing the history of change in the directory. I thought of check it into `git`, but then they can always delete the `.git` file, and there's gone the history!

Comment: You can use VCS saving its files in other place, where that users can't write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the user's `~/.bash_history` file and see if they have a `cd` to the folder you're checking out. This works if they weren't paranoid.

`stat -c 'Owner: %U / Access_rights: %A / Last_access %x' ~/`
 will print the owner username and access rights for your home directory. Change `~/` to the folder that you're interested in.

`last` will give you user login history with dates/times.

You can match all of these things together to get a good idea of the last user who looked at it.

Comment: I think you understand what I meant, thank you! :)

Comment: The first command shows me the timestamp when it was last accessed, but it doesn't say who. But unfortunately, there are A LOT of users on my system, hence, `last` doesn't help much ... Do you happen to know some other trick?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [inotifywatch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywatch), it listens for filesystem events then outputs a summary count of the events received on each file or directory